# A resposta HTTP 418 "I'm a Teapot" seria válido?

Tags: http-status

Uma determinada API está me retornando um status `418 I'm a teapot`, vi que faz parte do protocolo `HTCPCP`.

```
             ;,'
     _o_    ;:;'
 ,-.'---`.__ ;
((j`=====',-'
 `-\     /
    `-=-'
```

- O uso deste status pode ser considerado como um retorno válido?

Comment: Não acho que sua implementação deva ser feita em um servidor de produção, pois o mesmo nasceu de uma piada de primeiro de abril, mas existe até mesmo RFC: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418

Comment: @DanielMendes se eu fizer uma requisição HTCPCP para uma chaleira em ambiente de produção qual deveria usar então?

Comment: não seria válido usar esse código quando alguém tenta fazer algo que o servidor não faz?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O status 418 hoje é **reservado** ao "I'm a teapot", mas vou contar um pouco de como foi este processo.

Como já foi dito este status é uma brincadeira que surgiu em 01/04/1998, ou seja uma brincadeira de **"primeiro de Abril"**, até mesmo a Google o utilizou em um de seus *Easter Eggs*:

- https://searchengineland.com/new-google-easter-egg-seo-geeks-server-status-418-im-teapot-201739

No entanto o que falta falar é que este status foi proposto para ser removido, *Mark Nottingham*, presidente do IETF na época, solicitou a remoção desse status de algumas linguagens e bibliotecas, em resposta a isto, *Shane Brunswick* (um desenvolvedor, por algum motivo frisaram que na época ele tinha apenas 15 anos) criou um site chamado https://save418.com/ ("Save 418 Movement"), na proposta ele citou alguns argumentos em favor de manter o status 418, mas creio que a que mais convenceu as pessoas foi este argumento:

> ... It's a reminder that the underlying processes of computers are still made by humans.

Traduzido:

> ... É um lembrete de que os processos subjacentes dos computadores ainda são feitos por seres humanos.

Isto se tornou viral (ao menos entre o publico que é da área de desenvolvimento e participantes do reddit) que ocasionou na hashtag `#save418` em mídias sociais.

Com isto as linguagens e bibliotecas HTTP que pretendiam remover o status 418 optaram por mantê-lo, não porque ele é útil ou porque ele é aplicável, foi apenas pelos fatos ocorridos antes.

Estes ocorridos levaram *Mark Nottingham* a abrir um processo de tornar o 418 um status reservado para que no futuro não fosse substituído no futuro por outro uso, então basicamente é por isso que o status ainda existe.

---

Respondendo a pergunta:

> O uso deste status pode ser considerado como um retorno válido?

Validade é uma questão de contexto, sem contexto algum e falando apenas de HTTP dá pra dizer sim, ele é valido, mas usar por usar não tem nem sentido, assim como usar qualquer outro código sem contexto.

Reforço dizendo que mesmo sendo hoje um código reservado isto não significa que lhe será útil, a não ser que você **queira brincar também** (e ache isto prudente no momento), por exemplo, no dia primeiro de Abril em qualquer erro(s) HTTP especifico(s) (exemplo 404) você trocaria pelo `418` (desde que não afete quem for usar o serviço).

Resumindo a história, **não tem um uso real**, tem um apoio das comunidades e pessoas por motivações históricas e algum "apreço" a lembrar que as coisas são criadas por humanos ainda.

Você não precisa se preocupar em resolver este status, mas também se nota-lo em uma requisição de outro servidor que fizer, já sabe, provavelmente é uma brincadeira e provavelmente tem como contornar ou você com certeza caiu no lugar errado ou fez algo errado, para cair na tal brincadeira.

Answer (score 10):

O código HTTP 418 faz parte de uma especificação (RFC), que foi publicada como piada de 1º de Abril ([fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol)).

De acordo com a especificação, esse código é válido se você solicitou a uma cafeteira que ela faça café, mas o "servidor" não é uma cafeteira e sim um "tea pot" (chaleira?).

Mesmo não sendo uma especificação séria, várias bibliotecas e frameworks implementaram essa especificação como forma de continuar a piada.

Como a especificação nunca foi reconhecida pela IETF (órgão responsável por endossar as especificações relacionadas ao HTTP) teoricamente ela não é válida para um servidor de verdade. Mas, mesmo assim, nada impede alguns serviços de implementarem esse código.

Answer (score 1):

Por definição, todos os status codes que começam com 4 são status code de "Client Error". Portanto, você precisa considerar isso como uma falha. Os status de sucesso são os que começam com 2.

`418 I'm a teapot` é um status code feito como primeiro de abril e não deveria ser usado em produção.

Você vai precisar falar com quem fez o endpoint pra entender o que ele quis dizer com isso.